# Tkinter Checklist, how to get the value from a checklist

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to print the values from these check buttons but I keep getting "0". I have no idea what I am doing wrong? I would like for it to display "On" / "Off" or "1" / "2". Anyone understand how to do this? Please let me know if you need more context or you don't understand the question.

```
def autoemail(self):
   master = Tk()
   master.title('Last Week Info')
   master.geometry("200x400")
   master.config(bg="#4bb4fa")

   self.var1 = IntVar()
   self.var2 = IntVar()

   self.c1 = Checkbutton(master, text="one", variable=self.var1, 
   onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
   self.c1.pack()
   self.c2 = Checkbutton(master, text="two", variable=self.var2, 
   onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
   self.c2.pack()
   btn = Button(master, text = 'Start', command = self.send_email)
   btn.place(x=90, y=360)

def send_email(self):
   print(self.var1.get())
   print(self.var2.get())
```

Comment: You're doing it right, assuming that there's code in the "..." that gives the user a chance to interact with the checkbuttons before the print statements are called. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Using `IntVar()` for `self.var1` will raise exception when user has changed the state of `"2one5"` checkbutton and called `self.var1.get()`.  Should use `StringVar(value=" ")` instead.

Comment: @BryanOakley How does that look?